# Self-referential key added to the wrong record

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I've got a Users table, with a `referrer_id` column that tracks who invited the user to the site. `referrer_id` is the User ID of the person that did the referring.

Simple enough.

All the answers on here simply say to do this:

```rb
# models/users.rb
class User < ApplicationRecord
  has_one :referrer, class_name: "User", foreign_key: :referrer_id
  ...
end
```

And the corresponding migration:

```rb
class AddReferrerIdToUsers < ActiveRecord::Migration[6.0]
  def change
    add_column :users, :referrer_id, :bigint
  end
end
```

Here's the problem:

```
#  Let's create two users: Elon and my humble self

2.6.0 :009 > elon = User.create(name: "Elon", email: "elon@spacex.com")
 => #<User id: 6, name: "Elon", email: "elon@spacex.com", ..., referrer_id: nil>

2.6.0 :010 > me = User.create(name: "FloatingRock", email: "floating@rock.com")
 => #<User id: 7, name: "FloatingRock", email: "floating@rock.com", ..., referrer_id: nil> 

#  I'm referring Elon to the site

2.6.0 :011 > elon.update(referrer: me)
 => true
```

The output is inverted -- the referrer_id is set on elon, not me:

```rb
#  Huh? Why's his referrer_id nil??

2.6.0 :012 > elon
 => #<User id: 6, name: "Elon", ..., referrer_id: nil> 

#  The logic is inverted! Rails thinks I was referred by him, the wrong way roun

2.6.0 :013 > me
 => #<User id: 7, name: "FloatingRock", ..., referrer_id: 6>
```

Comment: Change your `has_one` to: `belongs_to :referrer, class_name: "User", :optional => true` and give it another try.

Comment: Works! Why though?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have fallen for a very common misconception about `has_one` and `belongs_to` which is due to the somewhat confusing semantics. `has_one` stipulates that the there is a one to one association and the foreign key is on the other side of the association - just like `has_many` (apart from the obvious difference).

`belongs_to` places the foreign key on *this* model. Or in the case of self-referential association says that *this* association corresponds to the foreign key.

```
class AddReferrerIdToUsers < ActiveRecord::Migration[6.0]
  def change
    add_reference :users, :referrer, foreign_key: { to_table: :users }
  end
end

# models/users.rb
class User < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :referrer, 
             class_name: "User", 
             inverse_of: :referrals 
  has_many :referrals,
             class_name: "User", 
             inverse_of: :referrer,
             foreign_key: :referrer_id
end
```

If you really wanted to make the association one to one (a user can only refer one other user) you would use a `has_one` that references the `belongs_to` assocation:

```
# models/users.rb
class User < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :referrer, 
             class_name: "User", 
             inverse_of: :referred_user
  has_one :referred_user,
             class_name: "User", 
             inverse_of: :referrer,
             foreign_key: :referrer_id
end
```

Comment: It *reads better* when I say "User has one referrer"; a single user can refer many other users though. I found it hard to differentiate this model vs that model when referencing the same class, but your explanation cleared it up! I now see why it's not enough to just have `belongs_to :referrer, class_name: "User"` and call it a day.  Thanks for the detailed answer